# How To set fotorama plugin to generate images dynamically?

Tags: jquery, django

I use jquery , I added in head tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link  href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.5.2/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.5.2/fotorama.js"></script> 



 $(document).ready(function($)
 {


 $.get( "getonepoi",{clicked:clicked_poi}, function(data)
 {


 $( "#picture_bar" ).html(data.picture_bar);

 $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title',   clicked_poi);
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );



 });
 });
```

html

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">

<div class="fotorama" id ="picture_bar"></div>
</div>
```

when I generate html code for images via $.get and add it

```
 picture_bar='img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">'
 $( "#picture_bar" ).html(data.picture_bar);
```

then slideshow fotorama, jquery plugin included in head don't works , but when I add code manually like

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<div class="fotorama" id ="picture_bar">
img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

then it works , anyone know why adding html in $get don't want to include other js,css  , when I click on Inspect element it all looks good , here I removed fist charachter for script and img tag , because stackoverflow shows then images instead code , so error isnt because of "<"img == img . 
My question is how To set fotorama http://fotorama.io/set-up/ plugin to generate images dynamically, $get  currently call django view   that generate imgs code ,

```
def get_one_poi(request):


if  "clicked" in request.GET:
    poi_name=request.GET["clicked"]
    pictures=Pic.objects.filter(poi_id=poi_name)

    picture_bar=""
    for picture in pictures:
    picture_bar+='<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'+str(picture.picture)+'">'
    picture_bar+='<img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">'
    print picture_bar
    response_data = {}

    response_data['picture_bar'] = picture_bar
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

???

Answer (score 0):

See, try to put the js code in the footer of your HTML code, so you make sure all the DOM is ready and loaded by the browser. Try this...

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var picture_bar = '<img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">';
  $( "#picture_bar" ).html(picture_bar);
});
```

Hope it helps!